# Dynamic sized array of pointers to class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, dynamic

Those are array contraints: array have custom size which i will read in top of program, this will be array of pointers to my own class Tree, array need constant read time to every cell.

This is my code which doesn't work:
    `scanf("%d %d",&n,&q);

    Tree *pointers = new Tree[n];

    pointers[0]->value = NULL;`

Comment: C++, it doesn't compile. Compile error: undefined reference to `Tree::Tree()

Comment: @PiotrŁużecki: That's a linker error, not a compiler error. If you don't mind me saying, if such basic things confuse you, perhaps fine-tuning the random-access complexity of dynamic arrays is something you should leave for a bit later...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `scanf`, ever. In C++, use dynamic containers and iostreams:

```
#include <iostreams>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  unsigned int n;
  int q;

  if (!(std::cin >> n >> q)) { /* error! */ }

  std::vector<Tree> forest(n);

  // ...
}
```

Depending on your setup, it may be preferable to read line-by-line first and then process each line; search this site, as this has been answered a hundred times before.

Comment: In this time i can't use vectors, because it can allocate too much space which i need. Is there any easy method like in my code?

Comment: Okay, so here are contraints: This array need to be well allocated in memory (not more than it needs), constant time to add value (on end of array), constant time to read any of value.

Comment: @PiotrŁużecki: wait, I apologise, I misunderstood you. OK, the vector I make should not actually over-allocate, because we pass it the desired size in the constructor. It *will* allocate more if you extend it, but if you already know the desired final size in advance, this shouldn't happen (unless you have a really terrible library implementation).

Comment: But i also need constant time to read every value in array which vector doesn't support. I will work with big data so i can't use it. Do you know any other way to make array like that?

Comment: @PiotrŁużecki: I don't understand. `vector` does have constant-time random access. It's really just a wrapper around an actual dynamic array. What exactly is too slow about that? You can't really do any better than a vector access-wise.

Comment: I will need constant time to random cells. Program will read data with some queries and in every query i need respond very fast. I can't predict which cell i will need in next query. Vector is too slow.

Comment: @PiotrŁużecki: Access to a vector is as fast as access to a raw array. You can't make it faster.

Comment: @Piotr Łużecki An `std::vector` isn't slower than a C array. It's exactly as fast (and if speed is a concern, also enable optimization on your compiler), unless the library implementation was written by a drunk moron.

Comment: @PiotrŁużecki `vector` _does_ have random access. In fact, a `vector` is likely to be as fast as a dynamic array. If you don't want to allocate too much memory, then just call `reserve` before you start inserting stuff in it.

Comment: Im really sorry. My apologize. You are all right. Thanks for help

Comment: @PiotrŁużecki: No worries, it happens to the best :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are asking about `C++`.

Your code will not work.

You can't dynamically allocate an array in C or C++ postponing the definition of its size at runtime.
You must use a pointer instead:

```
Tree *pointers =new Tree[n];
```

Don't forget to `delete [] pointers`

Comment: It's exacly what i wrote in first post (without delete part, but it's not problem here).

Answer (score 0):

if a pointer is declared, the syntaxes :
" *pointer " represents the memory location.
" pointer "  represent a pointer to a memory location.

Therefore, `Tree *pointers = new Tree[n];`new keyword returns a pointer to a memory location which can not be assigned.

I hope this solves the problem:

```
    Tree *pointers;

    pointers = new Tree[n];
```